# Indexes from inherited @NodeEntity do not return expected results

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a common entity class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Entity {
    /*** Common Fields ***/
    @GraphId
    protected Long nodeId;

    @Indexed(level = Indexed.Level.INSTANCE)
    protected Long id;

    @Indexed(level = Indexed.Level.INSTANCE)
    protected String someProperty;        

    ...
}
```

An Employee class extending Entiy class:

```
public class Employee extends Entity {

    @Indexed
    private String someOtherProperty;

    ...
}
```

I have noticed in my tests that:

```
@Autowired private GraphDatabaseService service;
Node node1 = service.index().forNodes("Employee").get("id", 1l).getSingle();
```

does not return any value, while

```
Node node2 = service.index().forNodes("Employee").get("someProperty", "someValue").getSingle();        
Node node3 = service.index().forNodes("Employee").get("someOtherProperty", "someOtherValue").getSingle();
```

both returns as expected.

I tried changing the name of "id" to some other literal and both searching with 1 (numeric) and with "1" (String) but it's still the same case. I suspect it has something to do with numeric values.

So I wonder maybe I'm using @Indexed in a wrong fashion?

Using:
neo4j-version: 1.8
spring-data-neo4j.version: 2.1.0.RC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing of numeric fields defaults to numeric values which are then stored in lucene differently, that means one has to use `NumericRangeQuery`, this is done internally in the `Neo4jTemplate.lookup`method.

If you don't want to index the data numerically use `@Indexed(numeric=false)`. Then it is indexed as a String and found by cypher and string index lookups.